# Javascript preventDefault() not working in Safari

Tags: javascript, safari

I am working on an application using javascript and I want to get mouse events. To stop the options that appear when right clicking I use the `preventDefault()` function and it works in Firefox and Chrome but it doesn't work in Safari. This is my code:

```
document.querySelector("#GL-Surface").addEventListener("mousedown", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    /* Handle mouse events */
});
```

From an other question I got that you should `return false;` but this still doesn't work. `preventDefault()` however works in Safari when it is used in keyboard inputs. So how can I prevent the default actions for mouse events in Safari?

Comment: Hey, can you try `e.stopPropagation()` or `e.stopImmediatePropagation()`. :)

Comment: @HalilÇakar Both commands don't work

Comment: Ohh, yea aight probably the result from @Wais Kamal is correct for right click events. also here is another one from stackoverflow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26032971/how-do-you-disable-click-events-from-the-contextmenu-event-when-using-ctrlclick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To target right click events, use `contextmenu` rather than `mousedown`.

```
document.querySelector("#GL-Surface").addEventListener("contextmenu", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Note that the options that appear on right click do appear only when the right click button is released, so I don't think `mousedown` is at all suitable here.